# Why does $x= \frac{1}{2}(z+\bar{z}) = \frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{r^{2}}{z})$ on the circle?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, line-integrals

I some help computing

$$\int_{|z|=r} x \, dz$$

by noting that $x= \frac{1}{2}(z+\bar{z}) = \frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{r^{2}}{z})$ on the circle but I don't understand why this is true. Why does the complex conjugate of $z$ equal this on the circle?

Comment: $\frac{r^2}{z}=\frac{r^2\bar{z}}{z\bar{z}}=\frac{r^2\bar{z}}{|z|^2}=\frac{r^2\bar{z}}{r^2}$ since $|z|=r$ on the circle.

Comment: Because $z\bar{z} = r^2$, when $z = r e^{i \theta}$ is in polar form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $|z|=r$.

Since $x$ is the real part of $z$, we have $$x = \frac{1}{2}(z + \bar{z}).$$

However, $z\bar{z}=|z|^2.$ Assuming that $z\ne 0$, which is equivalent to assuming that $r\ne 0$, we may divide by $z$ to get $$\bar{z} = \frac{|z|^2}{z}.$$

Substituting this into the first equation, and recalling that $|z|=r$, the result follows;
$$x = \frac{1}{2}\left(z + \frac{|z|^2}{z}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(z + \frac{r^2}{z}\right).$$